# Naming function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see in my code below, when I name my function `discount()`, the function does not run when it is called. However if I name it `discounts()`, it runs properly. Is there any explanation for this?

```html
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>q3</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="">
            <label> Enter Price:</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="name">
            <label>(RM)</label><br><br>
            <label>Enter Discount:</label>
            <input type="text" name="discount" id="discount">
            <label>(%)</label><br><br>
            <button onclick="discount()">Get Discount total</button><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="discountPrice" id="discountPrice">
            <label>(RM)</label>
        </form>
        <script>
            function discount() {
                var price = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var discount = document.getElementById("discount").value;
                var discountPrice = parseFloat(price) * (1 - parseFloat(discount) / 100);
                document.getElementById("discountPrice").value = discountPrice;
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code works fine as it is - `function discount` with `onclick="discount()"`  works just as well as `function discounts` with `onclick="discounts()"`

Comment: What do you mean by "the function will not work when called"? What happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Your code](https://replit.com/@codeguru/SilentTurquoiseCpu#index.html) gives the following error:

```
TypeError: discount is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:14:34)
```

The reason for this is that you have the following line:

```
<input type="text" name="discount" id="discount">
```

So when you use `onclick=discount()`, the name `discount` here refers to the `<input>` element, not the `discount()` function. You need to use two distinct names for these to fix the problem.

Comment: Can you please show a `snippet`, i can't get it to work.

Comment: @Blaze_droid you already found the solution. The function name cannot be the same as the `name` of any `<input>`. I'm merely explaining why you have to do this.

Comment: Oh yes, got it!

Comment: owh, I didn't know it is like this. I thought the parenthesis made discount distinctly a function rather than refering to the <input> element. Thank you :D

Comment: @BradLee Yes, when you do `function discount()`, you are creating a function named `discount`, but you also have `<input type="text" name="discount" id="discount">` which creates an `InputElement` with the name `discount` as well. Since both of these have the same name, the name `discount` refers to the most recent thing that was created which is the `<input>`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice btw how did you check the error, cause when i use google dev tools the console only shows the error for a seconds then refreshes so i cannot see what is the error

Comment: @BradLee I used `https://repl.it` rather than saving a HTML file to my screen. You might be seeing the page reload because the button is inside a form. To solve this temporarily, you can do one of 2 things: 1. Remove the `<form>`. 2. Add `type="button"` to the `<button>` tag. This overrides the default `type="submit"`.